# IBM MQ Security Switch behaviour on the z/OS

Tags: ibm-mq, zos

We have implemented message alert via zSecure to intercept MQ security disabling via message `CSQH021I` not realizing that a QSG profile is already in place on the production system to enforce security via `QSG.NO.QMGR.CHECKS` switch for the QSG members. There are non-QSG Q Managers also on the system and are making use of generic RACF profile `Q%%%.**`. This works fine but the generation of `CSQH021I` at each startup of the QSG Q Managers is intercepted by zSecure and creating confusion. We studied this document and has provided not the answer to our satisfaction to make a decision to remove this profile with impacting security.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q011490_.htm

Figure 1. Checking for queue manager level security
With subsystem security on, IBM MQ first checks for the `qmgr-name.NO.QMGR.CHECKS` profile. If this profile is present, queue manager checking is switched off. If the profile is absent, IBM MQ then checks for the `qsg-name.NO.QMGR.CHECKS` profile. If this profile is absent, queue manager checking is switched on. If this profile is present, IBM MQ then checks for the `qmgr-name.YES.QMGR.CHECKS` profile. If this profile is present, queue manager checking is enabled. If it is absent, queue manager checking is disabled.

We do not have any other security switches and this logic implies that the protection of queue manager is disabled, which is not true as far as I know.
Please help to correct misunderstandings or misinterpretations of this depiction.

Comment: Is the concern that on queue managers that are not part of a QSQ that protection of the queue manager is disabled? Toward the top of the page it states "`These checks are not performed if your queue manager is not a member of a queue-sharing group.`". Based on this I think that it means if it is not part of a QSG then queue manager level security is on and it would not matter if you have the `QSG.NO.QMGR.CHECKS` switch.

Comment: On your queue managers that are part of a QSQ it first checks if queue manager level security is on based on Figure 1: `qmgr-name.NO.QMGR.CHECKS` absent -> `qsg-name.NO.QMGR.CHECKS` present ->  `qmgr-name.YES.QMGR.CHECKS` absent -> Queue manager checks off.  It would then check if queue-sharing group level security is on based on Figure 2: `qmgr-name.NO.QSG.CHECKS` absent -> `qsg-name.NO.QSG.CHECKS` absent -> Queue sharing group checks on

Comment: I support MQ on distributed platforms and have no experience with z/OS RACF security, but based on the KC page you linked to that is my interpretation of things.  I hesitate to write it in a answer as it is outside of my area of expertise.

Comment: CSQH021I is issued for lots of different profiles. Could you update your question with the complete instance of all the CSQH021I messages you are seeing. Then I can compose an answer more specific to your problem.

Comment: @dhamial - Can you update your question with the actual CSQH021I messages you are seeing please?